# Python - Input within function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Not sure what is wrong with this code, I'm just starting to use Python 2.7, and have run into a problem with this bmi calculator script.

```
def bmi_calculator():

    print "Enter your appelation (Mr., Mrs., Dr., ...): "
    appelation = raw_input()
    print "Enter your first name: "
    fname = raw_input()
    print "Enter your last name: "
    lname = raw_input()
    print "Enter your height in inches: "
    height = raw_input()
    print "Enter your weight in pounds: "
    weight = raw_input()

    feet = (height/12)
    inches = (height-feet)*12
    bmi = ((weight/(height*height))*703)

    print "BMI Record for %s %s %s:" % (appelation,fname,lname)
    print "Subject is %d feet %d inches tall and weighs %d pounds" %    (feet,inches,weight)
    print "Subject's BMI is %d" % (bmi)
```

Would someone mind telling me what I am doing wrong?

---

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "a1.py", line 88, in bmi_calculator
feet = (height/12)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You need to convert the inputs to numbers, by default they are strings.

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast from `str` to a numeric type, such as `float`:

```
def bmi_calculator():
    print "Enter your appelation (Mr., Mrs., Dr., ...): "
    appelation = raw_input()
    print "Enter your first name: "
    fname = raw_input()
    print "Enter your last name: "
    lname = raw_input()
    print "Enter your height in inches: "
    height = float(raw_input())
    print "Enter your weight in pounds: "
    weight = float(raw_input())
    feet = float((height/12))
    inches = (height-feet)*12
    bmi = ((weight/(height*height))*703)
    print "BMI Record for %s %s %s:" % (appelation,fname,lname)
    print "Subject is %d feet %d inches tall and weighs %d pounds" %    (feet,inches,weight)
    print "Subject's BMI is %d" % (bmi)
```